# Random occurences of 502 Bad Gateway using Wordpress and Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am new to using Wordpress on Nginx and am seeing funny errors pop up here and there.

For a while when I was searching for a new plugin through **/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=search&s=captcha&plugin-search-input=Search+Plugins**, I get:
**502 Bad Gateway**

After a while, everything just started working again fine.

However, now when I try to access anything inside **/wp-admin** I am getting a 502 error again. The front end of the site works fine.

What are the steps to get things moving cleanly and to prevent this from constantly happening.

Comment: I'm actually running into this after changing a plugin I'm developing. While this didn't solve my problem, you might check here: http://www.nginxtips.com/502-bad-gateway-using-nginx/ and see if it helps. Good luck.